# Jquery tablesorter not working. Is it HTML5 compliant?

Tags: jquery, html, tablesorter

I am using a jquery tablesorter and can't seem to get it working. I have had it working in other solutions but can't seem to replicate it within a HTML5 project.

Following code is within the header in the Master Page;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery.metadata.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js" ></script>
```

Also in the master page, I have placed the Jquery. The table is created on the fly with a name of 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_memberTable'

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_memberTable").tablesorter();
    });
</script>
```

Front end code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/SSASWeb.Master"
    CodeBehind="MemberList.aspx.vb" Inherits="SSASWeb_HTML5.MemberList" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <h2>
        Member List
    </h2>
    <div id="table" runat="server" style="margin-right: 50px" class="tablesorter">
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Code to populate table:

```
Dim ScriptManager As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript
        Dim t As Table = HtmlHelper.ConvertToHtmlTable(ds.Tables(0))
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each row As TableRow In t.Rows
          If i = 0 Then
            i = i + 1
            Continue For
          End If
          Dim strMemNo As String = row.Cells(0).Text
          row.Cells(0).Text = ""
          Dim a As New HtmlAnchor()
          a.HRef = "NameAndAddress.aspx?member=" + strMemNo
          a.InnerText = strMemNo
          row.Cells(0).Controls.Add(a)
        Next
        t.ID = "memberTable"
        table.Controls.Add(t)
```

Function I am calling within the call from the back end code:

```
Public Shared Function ConvertToHtmlTable(dt As DataTable) As Table
    Dim table As New Table()
    table.CssClass = "hovered tablesorter"
    Dim tHead As New TableRow()
    tHead.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
      Dim cell As New TableCell()
      cell.Text = col.ColumnName
      tHead.Cells.Add(cell)
    Next
    table.Rows.Add(tHead)
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
      Dim tBodyRow As New TableRow()
      tBodyRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody
      For Each cell In row.ItemArray
        Dim rowCell As New TableCell()
        If Not IsDBNull(cell) Then
          Dim dtValue As DateTime
          If DateTime.TryParse(cell, dtValue) Then
            rowCell.Text = dtValue.ToShortDateString()
          Else
            rowCell.Text = cell
          End If
        End If
        tBodyRow.Cells.Add(rowCell)
      Next
      table.Rows.Add(tBodyRow)
    Next
    Return table
  End Function
```

When I go to run this and click the header, nothing happens but I cant figure out where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Put the code `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_memberTable").tablesorter();` after whatever code you're using to create the table "on the fly".

Comment: I can't as it is in .NET code. Ill provide the code.

Comment: the tablesorter definitely works under the html5 doctype.

Comment: thanks @KevinB. No idea why my code refuses to work then.

Comment: @Jacooobley if you replace `$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_memberTable").tablesorter();` with `console.log($("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_memberTable").length);` what do you get?

Comment: @KevinB it bring out a value as 1 and doing this with the original code in the console brings back 'message: "'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_memberTable").tablesorter()')"
'

Comment: Does the table actually contain a `thead` and `tbody`? I don't know asp that well so I can see the header and body are created, but I can't tell if they are wrapped. Tablesorter will not initialize on a table that doesn't contain both.

Answer (score 0):

mmm, for me there are 2 posible reasons:

1º Dont use:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="TableSorter/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

at the same time, choose only one.

2º May you can use

```
$("[id$=memberTable]").tablesorter();
```

Comment: check your console in chrome or firefox, what error javascript are you getting?

Comment: Try initializing tablesorter with the debugger on... `.tablesorter({ debug: true })`